# IntelliJ: Standard output while in debug

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm debugging my Java code using IntelliJ IDEA (Ultimate for that matter).
When on a breakpoint, I evaluate the following expression: `System.out.println("Hello World!")`. My question is: where does my greeting print?

I also have the same question regarding when similar expressions are executed in a conditional breakpoint. For example, having the following condition set to a breakpoint

```
System.out.println(x);
return false;
```

would allow me to inspect `x` without having to pause execution.

Thanks for any insights.

Answer (score 0):

> where does my greeting print?

Your output is printed into the console.

> having the following condition set to a breakpoint would allow me to inspect `x` without having to pause execution?

Yes, it would.